# Find eigen values of the matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Question from *Bapat-Spectral Theory*:

> Suppose $G$ be a graph with $V(G)=\{1,2,..,n\}$.Let eigen values of $L(G)$ be $\lambda_1\ge \lambda_1\ge ...\ge \lambda_n=0$ .Then eigen values of $L+aG$ are $\lambda_1\ge \lambda_1\ge ...\ge \lambda_{n-1}$ and $na$.

Using above  prove that if 
eigenvalues of $L(G)+J$ are $n-2$ with multiplicity $p$; and $n$ with multiplicity $n-p$,
 then eigenvalues of $L(G)$ are $n-2$  with multiplicity $p$;
$n$ with multiplicity $n-p-1$; and $0$ with multiplicity $1$.

I cannot prove this .Please give some hints on how to solve the above problem.I am really stuck here.

Comment: You are using notation which is unfamiliar to me. I can guess what $L(G)$ denotes, but would you please explain what $L$, $a$ and $J$ are and how the operations $L+aG$ is defined.

Comment: $L=L(G) ;a\in \Bbb R; '+' =$ componentwise matrix addition @CarlChristian

Comment: I do not understand how you add L (a matrix) to the product of $a$ (a scalar) and $G$ (a graph). I imagine that the notation $G$ is overloaded and denotes both the graph and another derived matrix? What is the matrix $J$? If it is the antidiagonal identity matrix, then why not eliminate any doubt?